# Dimensioned drawing of 64-pin SIMM?

Tags: apple-macintosh, apple, rom, simm

I am looking for a dimensioned drawing of a 64-pin SIMM PCB like the ones used in the Macintosh II series for the ROM SIMM. I looked in *Guide to the Macintosh Family Hardware* and *Designing Cards and Drivers for the Macintosh Family* and found the pinouts but no drawings showing where to put the holes and curved features on the board. Does anyone have this?

Comment: Have you checked JEDEC to see if the information you need is there? https://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/docs/module-441

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you likely need. However, note that I don't own a Mac II and I therefore can't be quite definitive. But I had a thorough look at Mac ROM SIMM photographs on the internet and it seems consistent. Unless they used some specific custom-manufactured connector that looks similar to the standard without being the standard, this should be it (just double-check the dimensions with the real hardware).

The Mac ROM SIMM is much taller, though, according to what I've seen. But the height isn't a critical dimension for fitting the card in the connector, the only limit being what the case allows for.

The drawing shows the 68-pin version, but the 64-pin version has the same layout, just look at the specific values for the A, F and E dimensions that I hilighted in the table. Dimensions are given in mm[inches]

[image]

Source: [TE/AMP 822033-2 datasheet](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Customer+Drawing%7F822033%7FL%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_CD_822033_L.pdf%7F822033-2)

Answer (score 0):

The Mac IIFX used a 64-pin SIMM for its main memory (1MB DRAM was
Apple part #661-0548).  28-pin socketed ROM chips (not modules) for the Mac II (original, 1986 model)
were #661-0639, -0640, -0641, -0642 if the model had the high density
floppy disks, and #342-0639...if the model  had the (original) double-sided 
floppy disks.

Other models (IIx, IIcx, IIci, IIvx, IIvi, IIsi) may have had plug-in
ROM modules, but which one?   Video card RAM, network card may have modules,
too.

At a guess, JEDEC standard MO-116 (for 1.27mm pitch SIMM socket) drawing would apply, but Apple might have used THAT standard for the DRAM, and could have
diverged for a ROM module to avoid confusion.